# HTML files or Core Data for storing large amounts of data in an ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, uiwebview, large-data

I'm making an ios application. I need to add the "Help, FAQ and Contracts" sections in my customer's web site to the application. These data need to be accessed offline so I can't use a UIWebView that loading these section's urls. These sections contain a lot of data and I don't think it is a good idea to use Core Data.

I think the best solution is to add these sections to application bundle (as html files) and show them using a UIWebView?

I don't know is there a more efficient way and am I doing a terrible job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is really useful when you have relationships between different Entities and you need to query the data like in "give me all the invoices from this date to that date".

In your case, you use static content to display the help screen so I think HTML files or text files in the main bundle is the best option.

Comment: Thank you Juan.. There are 500 hundred html files (all help documents, faq and contracts - no images) do you think will this be a problem? for apple approval?

Comment: I don't think so. Look, for example, some video games have bundles bigger than 500MB and of course they get approved. I don´t think that this will be your case.